# Ingore string using QRegExp

Tags: c++, qt, http, https, qregexp

I have a string in following format

qString path = https://user:pass@someurl.com

I want to ingore username and password from the the above path using QRegExp.
An worked with following case also

`1. qString path = http://user:pass@someurl.`

In the below case if it is does not contain any user name or passwod then return the string

```
2. qString path = https://someurl.com
```

My code is worked with http and https, Is there any best approach to do that is short and simple manner. please suggest

```
f(Path.startsWith("https://") == true)
{
    QRegExp UserPwd("(.*)(https://)(.*)(.*)", Qt::CaseInsensitive, QRegExp::RegExp);
    QRegExp UserPwd1("(.*)(https://)(.*)@(.*)", Qt::CaseInsensitive, QRegExp::RegExp);

    if(UserPwd1.indexIn(ErrorString) != -1)
    {
        (void) UserPwd1.indexIn(Path);
        return UserPwd1.cap(1) + UserPwd1.cap(2) + UserPwd1.cap(4);
    }
    else
    {
        (void) UserPwd.indexIn(Path);
        return UserPwd.cap(1) + UserPwd.cap(2) + UserPwd.cap(3);
    }
}
else
{
    QRegExp UserPwd("(.*)(http://)(.*)@(.*)", Qt::CaseInsensitive, QRegExp::RegExp);
    (void) UserPwd.indexIn(Path);
    return UserPwd.cap(1) + UserPwd.cap(2) + UserPwd.cap(4);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this with QRegExp? Use QUrl.

Comment: In `UserPwd`, group 4 will always be empty (as group 3 will always consume all the remaining text

Comment: @Jonas, I want to differentiate at runtime what it is http or https, does it contain username or password or not. that the reason I am using QRegExp.

Comment: @PrabhatChauhan Not surprisingly, QUrl (as a class designed *specifically* for manipulating URLs) has functionality to do *exactly that*!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved using  [QUrl](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html)

The following function manipulate the URL [authority](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#setAuthority) format

```
QUrl GetFixedUrl(const QUrl & oUrl )
{
    QUrl oNewUrl = oUrl;

    // Reset the user name and password
    oNewUrl.setUserName(QString());
    oNewUrl.setPassword(QString());

    // Save the host name
    QString oHostName = oNewUrl.host();

    // Clear authority
    oNewUrl.setAuthority(QString());

    // Set host name
    oNewUrl.setHost(oHostName);

    return oNewUrl;

}
```

Then call it

```
QUrl oUrl("https://user:pass@someurl.com");

std::cout<< GetFixedUrl(oUrl).toString().toStdString()<< std::endl;
```

Output will be:

```
https://someurl.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest two approaches. You can choose one, which is more convenient and suitable to you:

**Using regular expression**

```
QString removeAuthority1(const QString &path)
{
  QRegExp rx("((http|https|ftp):\\/\\/)(.*@)?(.*)");
  if (rx.indexIn(path) != -1) {
    return rx.cap(1) + rx.cap(4);
  }
  return QString();
}
```

**Using QUrl**

```
QString removeAuthority2(const QString &path)
{
  QUrl url = QUrl::fromUserInput(path);
  return url.scheme() + "://" + url.host();
}
```

**Usage**

```
QString path("http://user:pass@someurl.com");
QString s1 = removeAuthority1(path); // http://someurl.com
QString s2 = removeAuthority2(path); // http://someurl.com
```

Comment: what happens if my path contains some text example "How I can extract username and password from the path http://username:pass@someurl.com". I want to remove username and password rest thing same. In that case the above approach is not work.

Comment: It should work with regular expression approach. However your path should still start with `http://`